# Using a constant as host / ip adddress fails whilst using a string works, why?

Tags: python, influxdb

When I use a constant to write to influxdb, somehow it fails.The exact same code with a string works fine.

Code below works:

```html
def influx_write_dict(data_dict, database_name):

    client = InfluxDBClient(host='149.212.118.123', port=8086, username="InfluxDB", password="password")
    client.switch_database(database_name)
    print("Return code for influx write:", client.write_points([data_dict]))
```

But if I then try to do the same thing with a constant for the host address and the port. I get a bunch of connection errors, basically saying I cannot connect to the host. Reading works fine in both cases, but writing just produces an entire page of errors.

So this does not work:

```html
HOST_ADDRESS = '149.212.118.123'
PORT = 8086

def influx_write_dict(data_dict, database_name):

    client = InfluxDBClient(host='HOST_ADDRESS', port=PORT, username="InfluxDB", password="password")
    client.switch_database(database_name)

    print("Return code for influx write:", client.write_points([data_dict]))
```

Can someone explain how passing a constant differs from passing a string?

Comment: Both code snippets result in exact same call. You should look for the source of your problems elsewhere.

Comment: Yup, you are right. Thanks man. I had been staring at this for hours. Thanks for confirming I am not mad. This actually lead me to the solution pretty quickly. 

I had passed "HOST_ADDRESS" rather than HOST_ADDRESS, which made it into a string. TY!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was elsewhere. These calls are identical and using a constant is the proper way to do it obviously. My mistake was that I had passed my constant with quotation marks in my original code.